# Why does redis pub read io timeout occur?

Tags: redis

I am new to use redis.I have encounterd an io-timeout problem.
Code like this:

```
func main()  {
    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use enter code heredefault DB
        WriteTimeout: time.Millisecond * 100,
        ReadTimeout: time.Millisecond * 100,
        PoolSize: 20,
    })

    for {
        _, err := client.Publish("ch", strings.Repeat(strconv.Itoa(rand.Int()), 10)).Result()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

After several minutes, there will be a timeout problem. Like this:read tcp [::1]:54099->[::1]:6379: i/o timeout.
Is this because no sub or a slow sub? Please help me.Thanks!

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Golang, simple pub sub example

Answer (score 0):

100 ms timeout is pretty aggressive

The default timeout is 3 seconds in go-redis, it's not unthinkable that given a large sample (running a few minutes as you said), a few publish commands may be taking longer than 100 ms. It depends on your server characteristics and if you have other clients using the same server.

I'd recommend you use redis-benchmark utility to get a sense of the performance you're getting from your redis instance, to see how close your timeout is to the P99 roundtrip time of a Publish command

https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will do some benchmark test to find the P99 roundtrip time.